# getRequestURI for servlet or jsp?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jakarta-ee

I'm making a filter for my login form in my JEE project. I want to make sure you need to configure your session before you can access any pages past the login form. So, so far I have written this

```
public class AuthenticationFilter implements Filter {

 @Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest arg0, ServletResponse arg1, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest)arg0;
if(request.getRequestURI().startsWith("/"))    
}
```

In my `request.getRequestURI` statement, should I write the servlets or the jsp pages that the user can only access after passing the login form?

Comment: You shouldn't do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    @Override
    public void doFilter ( final ServletRequest request, final ServletResponse response, final FilterChain chain ) throws IOException, ServletException
    {
            doFilter( (HttpServletRequest) request, (HttpServletResponse) response, chain );
    }

    private void doFilter ( final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response, final FilterChain chain ) throws IOException, ServletException
    {
        if ( isAuthorized( request ) )
        {
            chain.doFilter( request, response );
        }
        else
        {
            response.sendRedirect("/login.html");
        }
    }


    boolean isAuthorized ( final HttpServletRequest request ) throws 
    {
        if ( request.getParameter("password").equals("swordfish") )
            request.getSession().setAttribute("authorized","true");

        return request.getSession().getAttribute("authorized") != null;
    }
```

This is sort of a "toy" implementation and doesn't follow many best practices, but it's easy to understand, I hope.